# SimpleDraweeView black filckering on replacement image with Fresco

Tags: android, fresco

I am trying to replace mutiples images (from local storage) using the same 
After a while the black flickering disappear and works well.

See the video: http://sendvid.com/q92ry52l

I am only doing: `mSimpleDraweeView.setImageURI("file://" + imagesList.get(index));`

The xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/fresco_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.13.0'

SimpleDraweeView. How avoid the black flickering?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*([full discussion here](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1468))*

Unfortunately this is a known issue. If you set a new URI, you'll see the placeholder image until the new image is ready. This is especially noticeable when you have large images and you switch them a lot (like in your example).

We are going to fix this at some point in the future (see this [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/pull/1328)).
For now, you can manually copy the `RetainingDataSourceSupplier` implementation from said pull request to your project and use it similar to the `MainActivity.java` example:

```
PipelineDraweeControllerBuilder builder = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()...
builder.setDataSourceSupplier(retainingDataSourceSupplier);
draweeView.setController(builder.build());
```

Comment: Providing some code for how to use "retainingDataSourceSupplier" would be helpful.